# No main manifest attribute error when running jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, runtime-error

I have create a maven project. It is running fine. Now i want to run my code through jar. After maven build i got a jar file in .m2 folder. When I try to run this jar using

java -jar "jar path"
getting no main manifest attribute, in "jar path".

My POM.xml is

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>main.Application</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

        </plugins> 
</build>
```

Please suggest how to get over rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want to run my code through jar

`exec-maven-plugin` is for executing a program during a maven build.

You don't want it. 
And as a side note, you don't have specified any goal for it.
So, it will do nothing.

You want to package your jar in a way that it is executable.
So use rather the `maven-jar-plugin`  :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                  <mainClass>main.Application</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

To create a JAR with dependencies specified in the pom, instead of, use the `maven-assembly-plugin` with the `jar-with-dependencies` `descriptorRef`:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>main.Application</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I did the suggested changes but  now i am getting  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error. As the projects POM include dependencies, but my jar doesn't seem to have these dependencies.

Comment: Because your project have some external dependencies. You may use the maven-assembly-plugin in this case. I edited to illustrate.

Comment: thank you david. but it didn;t help either.

i have added below plugin
    <plugin>
     <coomented the code >
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
It resolved my problem but getting the jar with a different name.

Comment: You should use the assembly:single goal to create the jar with dependencies.